# Missing RealmSwift.framework

Tags: swift, xcode, realm, carthage

I am using Carthage 0.32.0 to install Realm and according to the instructions [here](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/), `Realm.framework` and `RealmSwift.framework` should be created in my /Carthage/Build directory. I am seeing a `Realm.framework` file being created at /Carthage/Build/iOS but there is no `RealmSwift.framework` in the Carthage directory. I have `github "realm/realm-cocoa" "v3.13.1"` in my Cartfile. I've only been able to find posts from 3-4 years ago about this issue and they all seemed to be resolved by updating the Carthage or Realm version. Has anyone encountered this? If so, how did you resolve it?

**EDIT:** I should also note that I have the following:

- Mojave 10.14.3
- Xcode 10.1
- Xcode Command Line Tools 2354
- Swift 4.2

Comment: Hi.., I had a same issue when I switch to x code 10, I remove Carthage and install pods. and all issues resolved.

Comment: Could you add the Carthage output?

Answer (score 0):

This [post](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/6115) was the problem I was experiencing and the solution was to use the newly released version of realm cocoa (3.14.0).